# How To Change The Default Circuit

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, fusebox, coldspring

I am new to a company that is using fusebox. We need to run two versions of the application on the same box, so we duplicated all of the ColdFusion mappings from, say, "mapping" to "mappingD" in order to indicate these are the ones on the D drive.

All well and good.

In the D drive version of the app, though, while most of the settings have been changed to point to "mappedD", Fusebox keeps rewriting the parsed files to use "mapped" and I cannot for the life of me figure out where the heck to change the setting in Fusebox so it uses "mappedD" from now on!

We are using Fusebox with ColdSpring (which also has a new mapping of coldspringD) if that helps.

Comment: Usually, when I work with Fusebox, I reinitialize the application.  This can be done through the url `http://path.to.application/index.cfm?fusebox.load=true&fusebox.password=pass1234`

Comment: It's probably a shared application name - it's a common practice to append something like `hash(getBaseTemplatePath())` to the application name to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Thanks - my biggest problem was FINDING where things happened. Changed the value in fusebox.xml but that only wreaked havoc. Another guy told me the programs in /parsed were auto-generated so I killed a couple pertinent ones by renaming them and voila! most things started working. Still have a couple issues, but those are likely because we changed from cookie-based everything to session variables and it's still shaking things out. thanks for the help!